# Combo Box Binding Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I have had an issue with a C# Windows Forms program recently. I have a Dictionary that I am binding to combobox.

```
private Dictionary<String, List<TaskDueDate>> m_IndividualSheetDetails = new Dictionary<string, List<TaskDueDate>>();
m_CboxPerson.DisplayMember = "Value";
m_CboxPerson.ValueMember = "Key";
```

The `ValueMember` is the key which is a string value corresponding to a person's name. The `DisplayMember` is a List of objects. When testing in visual studio everything works as suspected and the combox box populates with a list of names. This is what the combo box should look like.

[image]

While this is what the combobox actually looks like once installed and run on the computer.

[image]

Apparently you need ten rep to post images so all I have is the links.
I am using clickonce deployment to deploy and install the application on other's machines. I am unsure why this is happening only on installation of the application. It runs fine and as it should in visual studio. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: you may use [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.format(v=vs.110).aspx) event on combo box for better handling of what you want to see there.

Comment: You're binding a `List` to each item in the `ComboBox`.  Flatten the dictionary into a `BindingList`.  Or `Format` each `List` if you want one row per item.

Comment: When you say _"when testing in visual studio everything works as expected"_, do you mean during design-time, or are you actually running the program in Visual Studio?

Comment: I mean when I run the project in visual studio to debug, the combobox displays as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have the ValueMember and DisplayMember exactly opposite of what you want..
DisplayMemeber is for display, and hence should be "Key", where as the ValueMemeber should be "Value"

Comment: That is what it seemed like but when I ran the project from visual studio it gave me result of image two when DisplayMember was equal to "Key" and ValueMember was equal to "Value".